# How to create www-data user?

Tags: 16.04

I am sort of new in linux ubuntu. I tried to deploy a Django app using Nginx.

Do i need to create `www-data` user in my linux? Or does it already exist?

Comment: You can check for the existence of the `www-data` user in a terminal with `id www-data`.

Comment: can someone please show how to create this user

Answer (score 8):

If you installed nginx from the standard Ubuntu repos, the installation should have created both the www-data user and group. Anyway the command to check if a specific user exists is (www-data example):

```
grep www-data /etc/passwd
```

or group:

```
grep www-data /etc/group
```

If you want to be part of that group you should do this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

obviously userName is *your* login name. Then logout and login again, and check with:

```
groups
```

if `www-data` appears, you are part of that group.

Comment: No need to `cat` into `grep`, just `grep www-data /etc/passwd` is enough. That said, usually you _cannot_ become `www-data`, as for security reason has `/usr/sbin/nologin` as a shell.

Comment: Yeah, deleted sudo su www-data from my answer ... seems that I have much more things to learn than to teach... :-(

Comment: I install `openresty`  `nginx fork`  it's looks didn't add  www-data user group , your answer didn't show how to create this user !